# Flutter state outside State object

Tags: flutter

I keep primitive states inside `State`. But for objects, the following works:

```
class _Like extends StatefulWidget {
    final Post _post; <-- mutable object is here

    _Like(this._post);

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _LikeState();
}

class _LikeState extends State<_Like> {
    ...
    _like() {
        setState(() {
            widget._post.liked = !widget._post.liked; <-- mutated here
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

What would the be reason *not* to use this approach? (As opposed to moving the state inside `State`, preferably as primitive `bool`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because `initState()` is in the `State` class, which your `StatefulWidget` can't call.  So your entire state should be in your `State` class to permit that.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll mark your answer as accepted if there's no better/official answer in a few days.